# Rotate OpenGL Object to Match iPhone Rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, rotation

I want to rotate a cube to match the rotation and orientation of the iPhone. In other words, each face of the cube represents each of the 6 sides of the iPhone. I need the cube to mimic the orientation of the iPhone. The code that I am using doesn't give me the desired outcome. I know Apple has provided and example with the GLGravity sample code but it seems overly complicated for what I am doing. Here is what I have so far:

```
 const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)(self.view.bounds.size.width) / (GLfloat)(self.view.bounds.size.height);
const GLfloat fieldView = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90.0f);
const GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(fieldView, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 10.0f);
self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

// ModelView Matrix
GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelViewMatrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelViewMatrix, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(modelViewMatrix, self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw);
self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the setup to test this, but I have a hunch that the problem is conflating pitch/roll/yaw with rotations around the X, Y, and Z axes. The axes don't change after you do each rotation operation, so you won't end up with the same final angle. Check out GLKQuaternion instead; quaternion math seems mind-numbingly abstract, but the GLK stuff makes it a bit easier. And it turns out to be how pitch/roll/yaw rotations actually work, so will likely give you better results.